# Tool to measure quality of javadoc with no source at hand

Tags: javadoc

I'm looking for a tool that can rank javadoc for which I only have the bytecode. A tool that would give an interface without javadoc comments a rank of 0, whereas a well doc:ed interface would rank 100. Cheers Niklas

Comment: Javadoc is a source code idea.  There will be no evidence of such in the bytecode.  How do you expect to make this measurement, with no data?

Comment: Lets say you have an API made up of a bunch of classes and a related javadoc artifact. Given that this is an ordinary setup for many API consumers, one would expect there to be tools rating the quality of the javadoc artifact given the actual API.

Comment: OK. Such a tool would have to parse the Javadoc as HTML, and pick out the apparant API, and match it against the bytecode. (You probably run serious risk of confusing javadocs and corresponding class files, so you probabaly really want a tool that takes a set of javadoc and a set of class files and returns you the maximum match and the ranking of each javadoc for that set).   I'm guessing you aren't going to find such a tool.

Answer (score -1):

Look into the JavadocMiner tool by Ninus Khamis